# Creation of momentum on vertex (quantum field theory)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, interactions

For a an interaction term like $g(\overline{\psi} \gamma^\mu \psi) \partial_\mu \phi$ in which $\psi$ is a Dirac spinor and $\phi$ a scalar field (d=4), should we expect this vertex to have a momentum associated with it (from the $\partial_\mu \phi$)?
If so, what is the meaning of a vertex "generating" momentum?

Comment: The first question is closely related to [Interpretation of derivative interaction term in QFT](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44202/interpretation-of-derivative-interaction-term-in-qft). As for the second one, who says that the vertex *generates* momentum? where have you read/heard this?

Comment: Thanks @AccidentalFourierTransform! The interpretation interaction was really useful. I didn't read on the generating of momentum anywhere, I was just confused for the momentum term on the vertex